# Custom tooltip callback on one dataset (chartjs v 2.5)

Tags: chart.js, tooltip

I have a doughnut chart with 2 datasets with a custom tooltip callback. I'm trying to hide the tooltip for one of the datasets. I have it all working, but I get a bunch of js errors when I hover the second dataset. Here is my
code:

```
    const data = {
        labels: ' . $custom_label . ',
        datasets: [
            {
                data: ' . $vdata . ', 
                backgroundColor: [ "#f56954", "#00a65a", "#f39c12", "#00c0ef", "#3c8dbc" ], 
                hoverOffset: 4
            },
            {
                data: ' . $cdata . ', 
                backgroundColor: [ "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff" ], 
                hoverBackgroundColor: [ "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff" ], 
                hoverBorderColor: [ "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff", "#fff" ],
            }
        ] 
    };
    const config = {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: data,
        options: {
            cutoutPercentage: 40,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: { 
                filter: function (tooltipItem) {
                   return tooltipItem.datasetIndex === 0;
                },
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var dataset = data["datasets"][0];
                            var percent = Math.round((dataset["data"][tooltipItem[0]["index"]] / dataset["_meta"][0]["total"]) * 100)
                            return data["labels"][tooltipItem[0]["index"]] + " " + percent + "%";
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var dataset = data["datasets"][0];
                            var value = dataset["data"][tooltipItem["index"]];
                            return "$" + (Math.round(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                    },
                    afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            var dataset = data["datasets"][1];
                            return dataset["data"][tooltipItem["index"]] + " " + data["labels"][tooltipItem["index"]];
                    }
                },
                titleFontColor: "#fff",
                titleFontSize: 14,
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                bodyFontColor: "#fff",
                bodyFontSize: 14,
                bodySpacing: 4,
                displayColors: false
            }
        }
    };
    var assetsChart = new Chart( document.getElementById("assetsChart"), config );
```

I'm assuming it's getting an error trying to read the ["index"] portion since it doesn't exist for  the second dataset.

EDIT: I updated to show the full code for my chart

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a really old version of `Chart.js`. You should first switch to the [latest version](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases) (currently `v3.5.1`).

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below and see how it could work using `Chart.js` `v3.5.1`.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [5, 3, 7, 6, 7],
        backgroundColor: ["#f56954", "#00a65a", "#f39c12", "#00c0ef", "#3c8dbc"],
        hoverOffset: 4,
      },
      {
        data: [2, 4, 5, 4, 6],
        hidden: true
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        filter: ctx => ctx.datasetIndex == 0,
        callbacks: {
          title: ctx => {
            if (ctx.length) {
              var data = ctx[0].dataset.data;
              var value = data[ctx[0].dataIndex];
              var total = data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
              var percent = Math.round(value / total * 100);
              return value + " " + percent + "%";
            }
          },
          label: ctx => {
            var value = ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex];
            return "$" + (Math.round(value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
          },
          afterLabel: ctx => {
            var hiddenDataset = ctx.chart.config._config.data.datasets[1].data;
            var value = hiddenDataset[ctx.dataIndex];
            return value + " " + ctx.label;
          }
        },
        titleColor: "#fff",
        titleFontSize: 14,
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        bodyFontColor: "#fff",
        bodyFontSize: 14,
        bodySpacing: 4,
        displayColors: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work. Even in the "Run code Snippet" it doesn't show the tool tip on both pie sections and gives errors on it. I would live to update to the newest version, but haven't been able to understand how to convert my code to that version. I'm including my full 2.5 code below and if there's any way to convert to 3.51 I'd love to.

Comment: @Robert: I adapted my answer with code for v3.5.1. I'm not sure however, how exactly you would like your tooltip to be displayed. From there however, it should be easy for you change the code and obtain what you're looking for.

Comment: I appreciate that. But when I run your code snippet above, and hove the 'two' portion of the doughnut, it doesn't show the tooltip. And there isn't a second dataset to verify it hides that toolset.

Comment: @Robert: I see that I misunderstood your question and just updated my answer once again.

Comment: Awesome! That works. Last question though... the reason for my second dataset is to be able to access that value on the afterLabel. How do I get the value of the second dataset in the afterLabel instead of the first dataset?

Comment: The final answer for what I was looking for is to use the following in the afterLabel:         var next = ctx.chart.config._config.data.datasets[1].data;
var value = next[ctx.dataIndex];
That work!

Comment: @Robert: Great you found the solution to the missing piece yourself! I updated the code in my answer accordingly. Please also note the `hidden: true` attribute on the second dataset, it can be used in place of the different color attributes.